# What tools/process could I use to achieve this finish?

Tags: machining, tools, wood

my son and I are doing a project together, but I’ve been struggling to find like a tool or process to achieve this ‘fillet’ I think it’s called, on the corners of this wood.

Any ideas please?

I have access to lots of tools at his school, like drills, jigsaws, milling machine,…

[image]

Also, for that bit I’ve highlighted below (where the wood goes from the thicker to thinner piece), how can that be achieved please? I thought about milling bearing in mind I’ve got a cube piece of wood

[image]

Comment: your question is better answered at https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/

Comment: probably a router

Comment: roundover bit in router

Comment: In addition to router bits, an appropriate jig or cam can also get you some reasonable results even if the radius is a strange one.  Sometimes you just have to clamp your parts and tools to 2x4s and go at it with the what you have.

Comment: Depending on the scale of these images, a simple piece of sandpaper might work fine.